# Magento 2, Change On click instead of 'hover' for menu

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, menu, navigation, category-view

In Magento 2 for the main menu, they dropdown with hover. How to change the dropdown on click instead of 'hover'.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 :** You need to remove the hover css for submenu.

**Step 2 :** After that you can add toggle event in the JS file for sub-menu.

Comment: It's adding inline css on hover. which js file i should customize to control it

Comment: @RaselUddin No, create new custom css and custom js file in your theme and implement your code in these file.

Answer (score 0):

more details and example can help thanks!